# Вывод данных из JSON

Tags: jquery, json

Просьба помочь!

Получаю JSON такого вида server1.php:

```
[{"name":"Kyocera 2523"},{"name":"Kyocera 4444"},{"name":"Kyocera 1717"},{"name":"Kyocera 4444"}]
```

Как мне вывести на страницу список имен?

Написан такой код:

```
 $.ajax({
                        url:"server1.php",
                        type:"GET",
                        dataType:"json",
                        success: function(json){
                           var s = 0;
                           var out ='';  
                        while(s <= json.length -1){
                       "<p>"+json[j].name+"</p>";

                         j++;

                     $("#book").html(out);
```

Где тут ошибка? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@shatoidil](/users/19734/shatoidil)](/users/19734/shatoidil)

> Где тут ошибка? Заранее спасибо!

1. лишняя запятая:

> Как мне вывести на страницу, список имен?

2. вы не конкатенируете данные, они уходят в никуда (внимание на переменную out):

```
while (s <= json.length -1) {
    out += "<p>" + json[j].name + "</p>";
```

Comment: Да, все получилось! Но еще дело было в переменной, которую я не заменил.